# ecplise cdt cygwin, how to set the lookup path

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I use ecplise, cdt and cygwin as the c++ IDE on windows platform. I use the eclipse 4.2. I don't know how to set the "lookup path", and what's the "look up path" means?

can anyone give me some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is the path where your source code should be located in order to compile it.

For configuration check out the [link](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_dbg_src.htm)